# Meaning of IRP_MJ_ACQUIRE_FOR_SECTION_SYNCHRONISATION

Tags: windows, driver, minifilter

I'm currently developping a miniFilter driver from scratch.

Right now i'm just trying to understand how all of this works, which actions leads to which IRP event etc...

After some tests with the miniSpy filter Driver, I can see those 3 Major operation and can't figure out what is done.

```
IRP_MJ_ACQUIRE_FOR_SECTION_SYNCHRONIZATION    
IRP_MJ_QUERY_INFORMATION           
IRP_MJ_RELEASE_FOR_SECTION_SYNCHRONIZATION
```

I'm usually using this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548630(v=vs.85).aspx

But I can't found `ACQUIRE/RELEASE_FOR_SECTION_SYNCHRONIZATION`.

Can someone explain me what they mean ?

Comment: You do get to see more than you bargained for, I'd assume that this notification is useful to people that write anti-malware programs.  Googling it predecessor, AcquireFileForNtCreateSection, might give better hits.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you might want to check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/flt-parameters-for-irp-mj-acquire-for-section-synchronization) out.

1. You can think of the  **IRP_MJ_ACQUIRE_FOR_SECTION_SYNCHRONIZATION** as callback for CreateaFileMapping. It essentially tells you that the FILE_OBJECT in question is about to have section object created for it.
2. **IRP_MJ_QUERY_INFORMATION** its the file-system callback for [ZwQueryInformationFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryinformationfile). Check that one out for more details on various information classes and what structures are behind each buffer for each class.
3. **IRP_MJ_RELEASE_FOR_SECTION_SYNCHRONIZATION** has no parameters. Consider it as an equivalent of CloseHandle(SectionHandle). Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/flt-parameters-for-irp-mj-release-for-section-synchronization).

Hope it clears things out.

Good luck.